# как в woocommerce передать id товара в jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть скрипт:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .add_to_cart_button', function(e) {
    $( ".post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .dobavlannovcart" ).show();

    var glavnikolvo = $(".post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .kuplukolvoinput .qty").val();
    var natovarkolvo = $(".post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .dobavlannovcart .qty").val();
    var res = parseInt(glavnikolvo) + parseInt(natovarkolvo);

    $('.post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .dobavlannovcart .qty').val(res); 
});
```

В данный момент он вставлен напрямую в php код, это не правильно.
И при 2ух одинаковых страницах скрипт отрабатывает 2 раза...
Как мне вынести скрипт в function.php или в main.js чтоб он продолжил работать как надо. Для этого я как понял мне нужно передать id в main.js или как-то сделать в function.php.

Comment: как насчет парсить список классов body регуляркой, а сам скрипт вынести в .js - файл и подключить через ```wp_equeue_script()```

Answer (score 0):

Так вызывайте его в хуке 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' ,

Для работы с товарами посмотрите [документацию](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)

Comment: Можете показать пример пожалуйста не понимаю в хуках